# Makefile with subdirectories with sequential numbering

Tags: makefile, latex, gnu

I have, in the main repository some subdirectories called assignment_1, assignment_2, ..., assignment_n.
I'm tring to write a Makefile that compiles the all TeX files inside those subdirectories.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
.PHONY: papers clean

PUBLISH_DIR := publish
TEX_DIR := .tex
SRC_DIR := assignment_$(wildcard *)
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.tex)
CC := xelatex
FLAGS := -shell-escape -output-directory=$(TEX_DIR)

all: $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.tex, $(PUBLISH_DIR)/%.pdf, $(SRC_FILES))

$(PUBLISH_DIR)/%.pdf: $(SRC_DIR)/%.tex
    mkdir -p $(TEX_DIR)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $<
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $<
    mkdir -p $(PUBLISH_DIR)
    mv $(TEX_DIR)/*.pdf $(PUBLISH_DIR)/

clean:
    rm -rf $(PUBLISH_DIR) $(TEX_DIR)
```

If I change this line

```
SRC_DIR := assignment_$(wildcard *)
```

with

```
SRC_DIR := assignment_1
```

it works beautifully but (obviously) only with the TeX file inside assignment_1.

Beside traversing the subdirectories, is there anything else I can improove in this Makefile?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should modify your wildcard:

```
SRC_DIR := assignment_$(wildcard *)
```

to

```
SRC_DIR := $(wildcard assignment_*)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$(wildcard *)` expands to `1 2 3` then `assignment_$(wildcard *)` will expand to `assignment_1 2 3` which is clearly not what you want.

Try this:

```
SRC_DIR := $(addprefix assignment_,$(wildcard *))
```

to add the `assignment_` prefix to the start of each word.